# javanullpointerexception after df.na.fill("Missing") in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been trying to learn/use Scala for machine learning and to do that I need to convert string variables to an index of dummies.

The way I've done it is with the `StringIndexer` in Scala. Before running I've used `df.na.fill("missing")` to replace missing values. Even after I run that I still get a `NullPointerException`.

Is there something else I should be doing or something else I should be checking?  I used `printSchema` to filter only on the string columns to get the list of columns I needed to run `StringIndexer` on.

```
val newDf1 = reweight.na.fill("Missing")


val cat_cols = Array("highest_tier_nm", "day_of_week", "month", 
  "provided", "docsis", "dwelling_type_grp", "dwelling_type_cd", "market" 
  "bulk_flag")

val transformers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = cat_cols
  .map(cname => new StringIndexer() 
        .setInputCol(cname)
        .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index"))

val stages: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = transformers
val categorical = new Pipeline().setStages(stages) 
val cat_reweight = categorical.fit(newDf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when using machine learning you would train the model with one part of the data and then test it with another part. Hence, there are two different methods to use to reflect this. You have only used `fit()` which is equivalent to training a model (or a pipeline).

This mean that your `cat_reweight` is not a dataframe, it is a `PipelineModel`. A `PipelineModel` have a function `transform()` that takes data with the same format as the one used for training and gives a dataframe as output. In other words, you should add `.transform(newDf1)` after `fit(newDf1)`.

---

Another possible issue is that in your code you have used `fit(newDf)` instead of `fit(newDf1)`. Make sure the correct dataframe is used for both the `fit()` and `transform()` methods, otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.

It works for me when running locally, however, if you still get an error you could try to `cache()` after replacing the nulls and then performing an [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) to make sure all transformations are done.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are correct sir! It is actually when I add the transform that I get the java error.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. You are correct that I had forgotten to add the transform to the pipeline. But the problem I am having is that I get the nullpointer error after I run the pipeline even though I have already used na.fill().

Comment: @jswtraveler My bad, should have read more carefully. The example code I posted I working very well and `na.fill()` should account for any nulls in the data, so it should be working. Are you sure that all the column names are correctly spelled? You can try removing all except one (that you know contained bill in the beginning) and test.

Comment: @jswtraveler Updated the answer with some more relevant information.